# 'net usershare' returned error 255: net usershare add: cannot convert name "Everyone" to a SID. The transport connection is now disconnected

Tags: linux, arch-linux, samba

When I try to add usersahre using nautilus-share pulgin I get the following error
`'net usershare' returned error 255: net usershare add: cannot convert name "Everyone" to a SID. The transport connection is now disconnected..`
my smbd.conf content :

```
[global]
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   dns proxy = no
   log file = /var/log/samba/%m.log
   max log size = 1000
   server min protocol = SMB2_02
   server max protocol = SMB3
   server role = standalone server
   passdb backend = tdbsam
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   unix password sync = yes
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *New*UNIX*password* %n\n *ReType*new*UNIX*password* %n\n *passwd:*all*authentication*tokens*updated*successfully*
   pam password change = yes
   map to guest = Bad Password
   usershare allow guests = yes
   name resolve order = lmhosts bcast host wins
   security = user
   guest account = guest
   guest ok = yes
   usershare path = /var/lib/samba/usershares
   usershare max shares = 100
   usershare owner only = false
   force create mode = 0070
   force directory mode = 0070
   load printers = no
   printing = bsd
   printcap name = /dev/null
   disable spoolss = yes
   show add printer wizard = no

[homes]
   comment = Home Directories
   browseable = no
   read only = yes
   create mask = 0700
   directory mask = 0700
   valid users = %S

[printers]
   comment = All Printers
   browseable = no
   path = /var/spool/samba
   printable = yes
   guest ok = no
   read only = yes
   create mask = 0700

[print$]
   comment = Printer Drivers
   path = /var/lib/samba/printers
   browseable = yes
   read only = yes
   guest ok = no
```

also i checked that my user is in sambashare group and the directory /var/lib/samba/usershares has the following attributes
`drwxrwxrwx 2 root sambashare   4096 فبر  5 19:11 usershares`

any suggestion with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I connect to a Windows host from a bunch of vbox linux and unix guests and was sharing files from the host on the guests without problems until upgrading to Windows 11. I had to turn on smb1 on Windows 11 for it to work on unix again. I think it was still working on the linux boxes.

I've been trying to connect Solaris and OpenBSD guests to the host through samba and am receiving a 'net usershare' error 255 in xsession-errors.

I see that the extended error says that it couldn't map a user to SID.

The first change I might try, if I were you, is to change the 'obey pam restrictions' back to no. It seems pam can't handle the lmauth challenge.

If that doesn't work, look into 'ntlm auth = yes'.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error message, trying to connect to a samba share. In my case the problem was that I had been previously experimenting with forwarding the samba connection to a different host, and netcat was still listening on port 445 instead of the local samba which should have been there. It appears that the smb client first connected successfully to nmbd on port 139 to find out the shares/names, and then connecting to port 445 but not finding samba there, or a wrong samba (not sure if the connection forwarding was actually working at that time).

So this was entirely my own fault. This is probably not applicable to the OP, but just in case someone does something similar, here's my answer to remind you!